# How to record if a specific change occurred across columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code I used to create my dataframe:

> ```
> data = [['Anna',1,1,2,2,3],['Bob',2,2,3,1,1],['Chloe',1,1,2,3,4],
> ['David',1,2,2,2,1]]
>
> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'A','B','C','D','E'])
> ```

I want to create a column which would state if a specific change occurred across the table. For example for this dataset I would like the column to express whether either the person went from '1 to 2 to 3' or '1 to 2 to 3 to 4'. So for this specific dataframe both Anna and Chloe would have an indicator in that column to convey that they went through these changes.

The expected outcome should have the following column to the dataframe:

> ```
> df['Column'] = ['1-2-3','NA','1-2-3-4','NA']
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the below approach:

```
cond=(~m.diff(axis=1).lt(0).any(axis=1))
df=df.assign(new_col=np.where(cond,
        m.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(map(str,(dict.fromkeys(x).keys()))),axis=1),'NA'))
print(df)
```

---

```
    Name  A  B  C  D  E  new_col
0   Anna  1  1  2  2  3    1-2-3
1    Bob  2  2  3  1  1       NA
2  Chloe  1  1  2  3  4  1-2-3-4
3  David  1  2  2  2  1       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
def path(input):
    nodes = []
    for i in input:
        if len(nodes):
            if i < nodes[-1]:
                return np.nan
        if i not in nodes:
            nodes.append(i)
    return '-'.join(str(i) for i in nodes)

df['path'] = [path(row) for row in np.array(df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']])]
```